# is it possible to subscribe to CloudAMQP rabbitmq service from android devices?

Tags: push, rabbitmq, cloudamqp

Is it possible to publish messages to the rabbitmq service by CloudAMQP from other cloud solutions like Appfog and consume them from internet(not inside the cloud) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can connect from anywhere!